# Creating dialogs programmatically from JSON file

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I am using the Microsoft Bot Framework with Node.js. I have a config file that looks like the following.

```
{
  "server": {
    "port": 3978
  },
  "dialogs": {
    "default": {
      "text": "This is some sample text.",
      "actions": [
        {
          "title": "Button 1",
          "value": "Action 1"
        },
        {
          "title": "Button 2",
          "value": "Action 2"
        }
      ]
    },
    "hello": {
      "text": "hello",
      "matches": "^hello$"
    },
    "asdf": {
      "text": "asdf",
      "matches": "^asdf$"
    },
    "goodbye": {
      "text": "goodbye",
      "matches": "^goodbye$"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use a for loop to read through the dialogs and create them so that they respond with the `text` value and have the trigger action of the `matches` value.

For example, the bot responds `hello` to the input of `hello`, `asdf` to the input of `asdf`, and `goodbye` to the input of `goodbye`.

The function I have written in an attempt to solve this looks like this.

```
var create = function(bot, _config) {
  var config = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_config));

  // Create dialogs from config
  var keys = Object.keys(config.dialogs);
  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var dialogName = keys[i];
    var dialog = config.dialogs[dialogName];
    // Skip over default dialog
    if(dialogName == "default") continue;
    // Create other dialogs
    bot.dialog(dialogName, function(session) {
      var text = dialog.text;
      session.endDialog(text);
    }).triggerAction({
      matches: new RegExp(dialog.matches, "i")
    });
  } 
}
```

When I run this, the bot responds with `goodbye` to the inputs of `hello`, `asdf`, and `goodbye`. However, the console shows that the correct dialogs are being called when they are supposed to. Even when I call the `hello` dialog by using `session.beginDialog('hello');`, the bot returns `goodbye`.

What seems to be causing the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a common “gotchas” of `var` in javascript. replace `var` to `let` should fix your issue.

The issue similar with

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 100 * i);
}
```

The root cause is `var` is function-scoped and `let` is block-scoped. You can refer to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html for details.